# make application with database MySQL is faster

Tags: java, mysql, performance, swing

I was creating an application with java and database is mysql and it was running well but when data get large (more than 500 fields) application running slowly , so How Can I make it fast ?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is determine what is slow. A specific user action? Where does the time go, is it the database? Is it the user interface?

Comment: 500 fields in a single table? You may seriously want to consider a database normalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For db

1. Add indexes for frequently searched fields
2. Think about table partitioning, rarely searched data should be stored in archive tables

For backend

1. Optimize queries
2. Minimize cursor fetching

For client

1. Use pagination to avoid large data loading
2. Use async loading (SwingWorker for swing, Service for javafx) to avoid UI hanging
3. Don't mix archive and working data in one UI form